# Cloning project from Github in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to clone a project from GitHub, but only some portion of it because the project gets too complicated for me. Is this possible?

Project Link: [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

This is the portion what I want to clone: [Targated Portion](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos/main)

**Note:** I have no problem cloning the entire project

Comment: what issue you are facing

Comment: If you have cloned the entire project you can open a specific demo by navigating to the directory through `AS` after clicking 'Open'

Comment: I do not know how to do it. I use code for all project import : git clone https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer.git ...... but what do I do for some?

Comment: yes, but I want to add the demo to my own project, and this is messy.

Comment: It's on another branch...`git clone https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer.git; git checkout release-v2;` and you're done?

Answer (score 0):

1. download github desktop https://desktop.github.com/
2. create a folder in your drive named github
3. open github desktop and go to create new repository
4. give your repository the name of your project and give the path 
   of your created folder(drive github).
5. copy your project from its package where it stored
6. paste it in the folder(drive github)
7. go to github desktop and simply Push the origin